# How do I schedule an action to happen in 5 seconds?

Tags: cron

I am in a situation that restarting the SSHD server along all it's open connection processes is required. So I thought that I might be able to use `cron` or `at` commands to schedule a service restart in a few seconds to the future (... and kill the process now). Problem is, both schedulers are not built for a few seconds schedules. For example: `at now + 1 minute` is a legit command while: `at now + 5 seconds` isn't a viable input.
Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: I don't think these commands support granularity less that a minute. You can write your own script: using a loop with a `sleep` in between.

Comment: "(... and kill the process now)" which process?

Comment: @muru - "(... and kill the process now)" - I run: "kill -1 sshd" (kills all sshd processes and terminates any possibility of re-connecting until the SSHD is restarted.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli the problem is that the running script must be off another process / parent process than the SSHD which is how I run scripts on the server. Otherwise killing the sshd process will terminate that script too.

Comment: @rubmz if you do that, `systemd` should automatically restart SSH.

Comment: @muru I didn't happen as expected last time for either: 1. the service status was up while the process was terminated, 2. the system takes too long to identify the process closed/service stopped or too long to restart it (should happen as fast as possible, and for at least a minute it was down) 3. somehow the service is not configured for monitoring/auto restart.

Comment: None of those seem very probable. Which version of Ubuntu is this? Have you modified the ssh service? What does `systemctl status ssh.service` show?

Comment: Can't you simply `systemctl restart ssh`?

Comment: @muru This is ubuntu 18. I just pkilled my sshd service again and I am not seem to be able to reconnect again... I did check the systemd init file and changed its restart param from "Restart=on-failure" to "Restart=always". Rest of params seemed pretty standard (it's an AWS machine...)

Comment: @danzel sshd service is keeping it's processes up on purpose on restart. It's this way since it's easier to keep open connections open. The problem is that sometimes you do need to hard reset one of the connections (which our case is not very distinguishable which sshd process it is...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the original question:

Instead of scheduling a job to run in a few seconds, you can schedule it to run `now` and delay execution at the start of the job. For example:

```
echo "sleep 5; wall Job executed" | at now
```

Note that `at`'s man page says about `now`:

> Indicates  the current day and time. Invoking at `now` shall
> submit an at-job for potentially immediate  execution  (that
> is, subject only to unspecified scheduling delays).

So it is possible that `at now` won't immediately execute the job, but at least on my 18.04 installation it does.

Comment: Nice and useful answer! So I marked it as the correct one.